# unable to position relative div using top & left attributes

Tags: css, css-float

I am creating a simple website layout which contains

header,banner,col1,col2,footer

with in the #col2 I have created a div with id #main-image. The problem is this I am unable to position this div using top & left attributes. This div is with in #col2 and #col2 has float left attribute on it.

```
#main-image {
    width: 343px;
    height: 312px;
    background: #c4b17e;
    position: relatvie;
    z-index: 10;
    top: -100px;
    left: -148px;
}
```

Comment: Could it be `relative` is spelt wrong?

Comment: Is `relative` spelled properly in the actual code?

Comment: Is it not moving at all or is your thing moving off of the page like in the fiddle below?

Comment: @Scott Brown it was spelt wrong in the code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelt `relative` wrong. Try fixing that.

Hope this helps!
N.S.

Comment: It was the most complicated situation I was ever been into, & the solution is amazingly simple. Thumbs Up for you & stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Check the size of the containing div.  You are inside of a containing div and thus if it is too small the contained div will not have any room to move.

When you have the containing div floating, most browsers will adjust the width the div so that it only takes up what is needed.

My recommendation: add a background color to #col2 such as #FF0000 which is red to see its width and height. If it is too small adjust the width #col2 to 800px or something like that.

Also fix the spelling of relative.